# CSS before and after not working with parallax

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply before and after for my div element which is a parallax element

```
<div id="OurPhilosophy" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-jhmi7y5v2c/product_images/uploaded_images/525231494.jpg?t=1489982505">
```

but my before and after are not being applied, I dont see them when I inspect element in chrome.

Here is my css:

```
#OurPhilosophy:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
}

#OurPhilosophy:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
}
```

Comment: ::before ::after instead of :before :after

Comment: nope that did nothing, interesting discovery, when i use : or :: it appys it to my footer, weird

Comment: because ::beofre or ::after is to add content before or after the div, so whats after the div? the footer i assume?

Comment: still did not work

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with before and after?

Comment: to have this around my div:  jsfiddle.net/AwadheshVerma/qemrb1ob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css then try:

```
#OurPhilosophy:before,
#OurPhilosophy:after {
    content:'';
}
```

Comment: this is fiddle url have a look. https://jsfiddle.net/AwadheshVerma/qemrb1ob/   this is working

Comment: I see the jsfiddle working, but no matter what I do, it keeps applying it to the footer

Comment: Whats after your div? the footer? also clear your cache

Comment: can you explain what you want exactly?

Comment: exactly whats in youre jsfiddle

Comment: an instagram feed and then the footer

Comment: actually it did work, I was just having container issuers

Answer (score 0):

```css
#OurPhilosophy:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
   content;"";
    top: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #999;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
}

#OurPhilosophy:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
 content;"";
    bottom: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #555;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="OurPhilosophy" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-jhmi7y5v2c/product_images/uploaded_images/525231494.jpg?t=1489982505">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#OurPhilosophy::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
 content:"";
    top: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #555;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
}

#OurPhilosophy::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
 content: "";
    bottom: -149px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #999;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="OurPhilosophy" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-jhmi7y5v2c/product_images/uploaded_images/525231494.jpg?t=1489982505">
```